# Jquery Ajax call Web Service API2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api2

I am calling an authorized controller on a web api service using client side javascript.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://10.0.1.18/WebAPISampleDB/api/values',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }

            });
```

Because I have not authenticated I should receive a 401 unauthorized message.  I see that it is a 401 unauthorized using Firebug, but when I try to alert the result, it has an empty responseText.

Using firebug and exmaining the Response Headers, it looks like the Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8.  And the 401 message response looks to be in html.

So from what I gather because my return type is expecting json and gets html it doesn't know what to do.

Is there a way to get the message of 401 unauthorized from the return of my ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(jqXHR.status);
   alert(textStatus);
   alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: jqXHR.status is 0, textStatus is "error" and errorThrown is empty